# 3D-graphing the $E_8$ root system/ $4_{21}$ polytope

Tags: graphics3d, graphs-and-networks, 3d-printing

I'm trying to recreate on Mathematica the 3D graphs $4_{21}$ polytope as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_21_polytope#/media/File:E8_3D.png) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4_21_polytope#/media/File:E8-3Dprint-b.png).

My idea would be to obtain a 3D-graph so that I can then add some thickness to the edges and export it as a STL file.

I think I managed to produce the $4_{21}$ using this code I've found [here](http://theoryofeverything.org/):

```
    (Permutation funtctions)
pm@n_ := Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ Table[{-1, 1}, {n}]], n - 1];
perms8[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, g_, h_}] := 
  Flatten[Permutations@{a #1, b #2, c #3, d #4, e #5, f #6, g #7, 
       h #8} & @@@ pm@8, 1];
Eperms8@in_ := Select[perms8@in, EvenQ@Count[Sign@#, -1] &];

( E8 4_21 vertices scaled for Max Norm=1 from Unimodular C600 and \
it's 3D E8->H4 projection basis)
e8421 =\[CapitalPhi] Union@
     Join[Eperms8@{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}/2, 
      perms8@{1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}](**)/Sqrt[2](**);
Length@%
```

I'm not sure how to move from here onwards...

Answer (score 5):

Here's a brute-force method for generating a 3D embedding of the graph of the $4_{21}$ polytope:

```
verts = Join[Union[Flatten[Permutations /@
                           Join[PadRight[Tuples[{-2, 2}, 2], {Automatic, 8}], 
                                PadRight[Table[ConstantArray[-1, 2 k], {k, 3}],
                                         {Automatic, 8}, 1]], 1]], 
             {ConstantArray[-1, 8], ConstantArray[1, 8]}];
edges = Select[Position[DistanceMatrix[verts] - Sqrt[8], 0], Apply[Less]];

Graph3D[Range[Length[verts]], UndirectedEdge @@@ edges]
```

[image: 4_21 polytope]

It looks quite a bit messy, so I'm not sure about the feasibility of 3D-printing something from this version. Hopefully, other people can build and improve on this...